# When combining controllers I get all the code as in the console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a problem and I need help with a solution I've been stuck for days.

I would like to display the contact log scaffold output for each 'tuning' client I have on my piano tuning application.

On my view I should be able to input

```
<%= tuning.contacteds.each do |c| %> <% c.comments %> <% end %>
```

What I get is a chunky console looking piece of code

```
[#<Contacted id: 6, method: "Text", date: "2018-04-19", comments: "I don't want to ", tuning_id: 22, created_at: "2019-04-19 06:05:58", updated_at: "2019-04-23 16:05:37", response: "", references: nil>, #<Contacted id: 7, method: "Text", date: "2019-04-22", comments: "Hes nice", tuning_id: 22, created_at: "2019-04-22 01:56:00", updated_at: "2019-04-22 01:56:00", response: "Yes", references: nil>]
```

It has no formatting and appears to show every piece of data when I'm just wanting the comments, and would like to add just the date and colour it if I got a response

What do I need in the controller for this view or on my controller in general to be able to pull up all the records for an associated model on an index file of my main controller, NOT on the invidiual 'show' page which I've already achieved. THANK YOU for your help! Evan

Answer (score 0):

The `=` after `<%` tells ERB to output the results of the code. Since you want to output the comments, not the array of records, move the `=` to the comment block like so:

```
<% tuning.contacteds.each do |c| %> <%= c.comments %> <% end %>
```

Comment: Perfect, that's saved me so many hours, sending you a virtual embrace